# How to compile the demo example of SoLoud library in C?

Tags: c, linux, audio, compilation

I planned to use the SoLoud library (https://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/index.html) for my C project. I can't understand how to compile the C demo file contained in

```
/demos/c_test/
```

to make it executable.
Can someone help me to understand how to compile it using gcc?

Comment: Hey @4nTO! Please provide some additional information: what did you already try, what type of errors did you get? What platform do you use?

Answer (score 0):

in the demos/c_test/main.c,

I changed:

```
#include "soloud_c.h"
```

to

```
#include "../../include/soloud_c.h"
```

and it compiled.  However, the compiler output the following warnings:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "main.c" -o "main.o"  main.c: 

In function ‘generate_sample’:

main.c:72:38: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   72 |   buf[i] += (((rand() % 1024) - 512) / 512.0f) *
      |                                      ^

main.c:75:36: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   75 |   float fade = (44100 * 10 - base) / (44100 * 10.0f);
      |                                    ^

main.c: In function ‘main’:

main.c:129:14: warning: unused parameter ‘parc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
  129 | int main(int parc, char ** pars)
      |          ~~~~^~~~

main.c:129:28: warning: unused parameter ‘pars’ [-Wunused-parameter]
  129 | int main(int parc, char ** pars)
      |                    ~~~~~~~~^~~~

Compilation finished successfully.
```

Note: I did not bother to link the executable, however, I did note a few items of interest.

1. the available libraries are *.dll files, so this is expecting to be compiled/linked under the windows OS.
2. under the 'bin' directory are the libraries:  soloud_x64.dll, soloud_x86.dll and SDL2.dll.  I don't know which of these libraries your specific computer will need to include

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already successfully compiled the program but I coudn't make the executable. I forgot to specify that I need to do it on Ubuntu, is it possible or this library is meant to use only on Windows?

Comment: (I think) that ubuntu linux does not recognize *.dll libraries